# Adding a global action in EasyAdmin, place my button underneath the table instead of above

Tags: php, symfony, easyadmin

I created a global Action :

```php
public function export(
        Admin $user,
        StructureRepository $structureRepository,
        ExportCsvEntity $exportCsvEntity,
        string $entityClass
    ): HttpFoundationResponse {
        $zipcodes = $structureRepository->getZipcodesByStructureFromAdmin($user->getId());

        $exportCsvEntity->export(
            $zipcodes,
            $entityClass
        );

        return $exportCsvEntity->download($entityClass);
    }

    public function exportButton(): Action
    {
        return Action::new('export', 'admin.crud.user.field.activities_tracking.button.export')
            ->linkToCrudAction('export')
            ->displayAsLink()
            ->setCssClass('btn btn-primary')
            ->createAsGlobalAction()
        ;
    }
```

Then in my Crud Controller I call it :

```php
if ($this->getUser() instanceof Admin) {
            $export = $this->exportAction->exportButton();

            $actions->add(Crud::PAGE_INDEX, $export);
          
        }
```

In the [doc](https://symfony.com/bundles/EasyAdminBundle/current/actions.html#global-actions) its written => `Global actions are displayed above the listed entries.`
But in my case the button is underneath the table
[Have a look here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dIPpo.png)

My template is extending `'@!EasyAdmin/crud/index.html.twig'`then I override the *global_actions* block :

```
{% block global_actions %}
     {{ parent() }}
{% endblock global_actions %}
```

Now my button is above the table but also underneath :
[Have a look here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fB1dX.png)

What do I do wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct when trying to do this by overriding the index template.

An easy way to do this considering how the template is organized is to modify the `global_actions` block by filtering actions you do not want to show above the list. For example by using a css class to **not** show a global action above the list.

```
{% block global_actions %}
    <div class="global-actions">
        {% for action in global_actions|filter(a => 'under-list' not in a.cssClass) %}
            {{ include(action.templatePath, { action: action }, with_context = false) }}
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
{% endblock global_actions %}
```

And in your crud controller:

```
Action::new('customAction', $label, $icon)
    ->addCssClass('under-list')
    ->createAsGlobalAction()
    ->linkToCrudAction('customAction');
```

And you need to add your new list of actions under your list by overriding the `main` block.

```
{% block main %}
    {{ parent() }}
    {% block under_list_global_actions %}
        <div class="under-list-global-actions">
            {% for action in global_actions|filter(a => 'under-list' in a.cssClass) %}
                {{ include(action.templatePath, { action: action }, with_context = false) }}
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    {% endblock under_list_global_actions %}
{% endblock main %}
```

And you should get your custom global action (with the css class `under-list`) under your list.